# Why should we assume that only the positive part of a submartingale is integrable?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

In [*Stochastic Integration Theory* by Peter Medvegyev](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/stochastic-integration-theory-9780199215256?cc=de&lang=en&), the author assumes that only the "negative part" $M^-:=\max(-M,0)$ of a supermartingale $M$ is integrable. Analogously, he assumes that only the "positive part" $N^+:=\max(N,0)$ of a submartingale $N$ is integrable.

Clearly, that's enough to ensure that all occuring integrals are well-defined. But what's the point of this assumption? Why he doesn't assume that $M^+$ and $N^-$ are integrable?

Comment: Where in the book is this stated?

Comment: @ZacharySelk In the definition a submartingale: Definition 1.49 in my copy.

Comment: Most authors define submartingales to be integrable. I don't get why he makes the distinction.

Comment: @ZacharySelk As I wrote in the question, I especially don't get why he's explicitly assuming that positive/negative part of a sub-/supermartingale is integrable. If the only point would be well-definedness of the integrals, he could for both just assume that at least one these parts (no matter which one exactly) is integrable.

Comment: Yeah, it's a weird assumption. Just go with it I guess and hopefully someone can come along and answer the question

Comment: How does one even define $E[X|\mathcal F]$ if $X$ is not integrable?

Comment: @Shalop In order to define $\operatorname E[X\mid\mathcal F]$, only integrability of $X^+$ **or** $X^-$ is necessary.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Ya you are right. I guess that's the answer to your question. In order to define $E[X_t|\mathcal F_s]$ you only need $X_t^+$ or $X_t^-$ to be integrable. And for a supermartingale, the negative part is the more natural quantity since that's the one which is important to prove the upcrossing lemma and the martingale convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Submartingales where originally defined as such and that is a weaker condition that leads to the convergence theorem (see Doob's Stochastic processes). Nowadays most authors just adopt the stricter condition of absolute integrability, which is what you propose.